# Can someone explain how to use search bar in iOS 8. "searchDisplayController" deprecated.

Tags: ios, xcode, search, tableview, searchbar

Someone please help me with searching a table view in iOS 8 using Objective C. 
The protocols have changed and searchDisplayController has been deprecated.
I found Apple's sample code but couldn't understand it so don't paste the same link again.

Comment: You have to use `UISearchController`.

Answer (score 1):

You use an UISearchController. To use it you first initialize it with `initWithSearchResultsController:` and pass it a view controller instance that should be used to display the search results. You can also pass in `nil` instead of a view controller if you want to show your results in the same view controller.

Then you get the search controller's search bar from it's `searchBar` property and add it to your view hierarchy, maybe as a table view header or somewhere else.

That is all for the basic setup. If you tap in your search bar the screen get dimmed, and as soon as you type something in there your search results controller you passed to the initializer will be displayed.

To be able to react to changes in the search bar you can either set it's delegate property or you can set the `searchResultsUpdater` property of the  search controller to an object that implements `updateSearchResultsForSearchController:` (via the UISearchResultsUpdating protocol). This will be called any time something in the search bar changes. Usually you will implement this in your search results view controller, but you can put it in other places too.

Since UISearchController is a subclass of UIViewController you can also present it manually like a regular view controller without adding it's search bar to a different view controller's view.

All this has to be done in code, it cannot be set up in Interface Builder.